Prevent Maven from compiling with an older transitive dependency version
In my Maven project, I have the following dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projectA</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

This dependency includes a transitive dependency on projectB version 2.2.0.
Additionally, I have another direct dependency on an older version of the same library:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projectB</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

How can I ensure that my project fails to compile if an older version (e.g., 2.1.0) of projectB is used, and always enforces version with is used by projectA?
I want to prevent the project from accidentally using a lower version of the projectB dependency.
Thanks for your help!

If you know that projectA has the dependency, why not remove your direct dependency and just use the transitive dependency instead?

There are ways to enforce the "newer" version. I would, however, advice against using those ways. The "proper" way is to upgrade the version of projectB in projectA (if it is a n internal library, this should be easy; if it is an open-source library, we can provide a MR, if it is a payed software we can contact the vendor). Everything else may lead to a dependency management nightmare.

Maven should use the highest dependency found (i.e. direct first, then 1st level transitive, etc.) and the first if there are multiple at the same level. So adding a direct dependency should make it use that one even if there are newer versions pulled in transitively. One issue that Turing85 is referring to is that projectA might fail to run with a newer version of projectB so you'd need to make sure this dependency is upgraded.

You can use the requireUpperBoundDeps rule of the Maven enforcer plugin:
https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireUpperBoundDeps.html
which is made for situations like this.
